# Laravel Envoy to SSH into bastion server, then, SSH into individual private web servers, stdout is split into new lines

Tags: laravel, bash, stdout, stdin, laravel-envoy

Our infrastructure/challenges are interesting, and I'm not finding anything too relevant online or on other SO questions.

Our `build` server is in a different VPC to our web servers, which are private. So `build` > `web server` isn't possible. I'm working locally with two VirtualBox VMs for proof of concept, no issues there. All works ok locally, using the two VMs.

Our deployments will be `build` > `bastion` > `webserver`.

I'm working on some Envoy scripts which will be trigged by GitLab's CI, which:

- SSH into our `build` server
- run `envoy run deploy:code --arg1=a --arg2=b --arg3=c`
- envoy then SSH's into our bastion server
- runs another script (Envoy eventually `deploy.sh` for now) to deploy code to our private web servers

VM1 `Envoy.blade.php`:

```
@task('deploy:code', ['on' => 'web'])
    ssh ubuntu@10.0.2.15 -p 22 -tt
    /home/ubuntu/deploy.sh
@endtask
```

VM2 `deploy.sh`:

```
$ cat deploy.sh
echo "hello!"
```

Localhost command:

```
 envoy run deploy:code --a=a --b=b --c=c
```

output:

```
[ubuntu@127.0.0.1 -p 10022]: /home/ubuntu/deploy.sh
[ubuntu@127.0.0.1 -p 10022]: Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-193-generic x86_64)
[ubuntu@127.0.0.1 -p 10022]: * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
[ubuntu@127.0.0.1 -p 10022]: * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
[ubuntu@127.0.0.1 -p 10022]: * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage
[ubuntu@127.0.0.1 -p 10022]: 105 packages can be updated.
[ubuntu@127.0.0.1 -p 10022]: 86 updates are security updates.
[ubuntu@127.0.0.1 -p 10022]: New release '18.04.5 LTS' available.
[ubuntu@127.0.0.1 -p 10022]: Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
[ubuntu@127.0.0.1 -p 10022]: Last login: Fri Aug 27 15:51:11 2021 from 10.0.2.15
[ubuntu@127.0.0.1 -p 10022]: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
[ubuntu@127.0.0.1 -p 10022]: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ /h
[ubuntu@127.0.0.1 -p 10022]: ome
[ubuntu@127.0.0.1 -p 10022]: /ub
[ubuntu@127.0.0.1 -p 10022]: un
[ubuntu@127.0.0.1 -p 10022]: tu/
[ubuntu@127.0.0.1 -p 10022]: depl
[ubuntu@127.0.0.1 -p 10022]: oy.
[ubuntu@127.0.0.1 -p 10022]: sh
[ubuntu@127.0.0.1 -p 10022]: hello!
[ubuntu@127.0.0.1 -p 10022]: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Can anyone suggest ways I can not have the output split over many lines, and instead just echo `hello!` after the welcome message/MOTD, and/or not have the output over many lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fresh Monday morning eyes led me here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/572412/when-running-local-script-on-remote-server-via-multiple-ssh-script-is-split-int

replacing

```
ssh ubuntu@10.0.2.15 -p 22 -tt
```

with

```
ssh ubuntu@10.0.2.15 -p 22 -t
```

caused:

> Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

A cheeky search later, suggested changing `-t` to `-T`

https://appuals.com/fix-pseudo-terminal-will-not-be-allocated-because-stdin-is-not-a-terminal/

```
ssh ubuntu@10.0.2.15 -p 22 -T
```

did the trick

```
[ubuntu@127.0.0.1 -p 10022]: Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-193-generic x86_64)
[ubuntu@127.0.0.1 -p 10022]: * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
[ubuntu@127.0.0.1 -p 10022]: * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
[ubuntu@127.0.0.1 -p 10022]: * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage
[ubuntu@127.0.0.1 -p 10022]: 105 packages can be updated.
[ubuntu@127.0.0.1 -p 10022]: 86 updates are security updates.
[ubuntu@127.0.0.1 -p 10022]: New release '18.04.5 LTS' available.
[ubuntu@127.0.0.1 -p 10022]: Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
[ubuntu@127.0.0.1 -p 10022]: hello!
```